# Problems with finding the unit cell from a CIF file and extracting XYZ coordinates using a software

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography, vesta, mercury

I got hold of a CIF file for a material that I am interested in. I am trying to isolate the xyz coordinates of the molecules. However, when I open the CIF file in VESTA, I get a near-infinite periodic structure. See the attached image:

[image]

Furthermore, in VESTA, if I go to `edit -> crystal structure -> systems` and then `choose molecule`, I can reduce the system to a molecule. However, it looks quite weird, especially in regards to side groups. I believe that two possible representations of the side groups might have gotten super-imposed on each other. See the attached picture. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

From the CCDC website, I was able to get a proper image of the unit cell I am looking for.

[image].

The CDCC webpage with the CIF file is available in [this link](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=1579467&DatabaseToSearch=Published).

I am using VESTA and I have access to pyMOL, GaussView and the free version of Mercury. Ideally I would like to isolate the xyz coordinates of one of the dimers in the unit cell, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I think that you need to change the title of your post. It began as a visualization problem and ended with "how to export to xyz". Regarding this question, please take a look at a very similar post [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1606/24)

Comment: +1 But please do take a look at my [edits](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/posts/5023/revisions) so that others don't have to do this type of work in the future to keep our standards up. For example, the word "I" always has to be capitalized.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I will try to keep this in mind, English is not my first language so it is not always easy for me to formulate questions . I will try to not inconvenience the community with my errors again.

Answer (score 10):

If you haven't figured it out yet here is what I would've done using mercury to get the xyz file of the dimer. There is some disorder in the crystal structure which I think means that there are partial occupations of molecules/atoms at different positions so you need to delete them to get only one of set of the dimers in the xyz file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Great first answer and welcome to our new community! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!!